# kafka connect elasticsearch connector (sink) data move in (almost) real-time

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect

interested in moving data from kafka to elasticsearch. so i have setup [kafka connect elasticsearch connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html).

although i reviewed all the documentation and the [configuration](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/configuration_options.html), i have yet found how to configure the connector to move data from kafka to elasticsearch in (near) real-time.

that is, making the connector consume message from the (kafka) topic each second and write them into elasticsearch, mimking streaming of messages from kafka to elasticsearch.

this is the current configuration for the connector:

```
{
  "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "foo",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
    "type.name": "kafka-connect",
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink"
  }
}
```

how does the connector need to be configured so it'll "stream" message from kafka to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Kafka Sink Connector` is based on `consumer`, you can control polling interval via [consumer properties](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) (e.g. `max.poll.interval.ms`, `max.poll.records`). To configure, just add consumer property with prefix `consumer.` to your connector config:

> consumer.max.poll.records=1

Comment: to make sure i got right, you mean modifying the json i posted to include `"consumer.max.poll.records": "1"`?

Comment: Yes. Here it is [example](https://github.com/EthVM/EthVM/blob/da2ab55daaf30755d2ec105b28811ee57c3f9e5f/docker/images/ethvm-utils/opt/ethvm/kafka-connect/sinks/contract-metadata-sink.json#L11)

Comment: not sure it is working for me. maybe my issue is with the elasticsearch, though i see no errors in its logs.

Comment: scaled the elasticsearch cluster to 3 nodes and still having the same issue - even when the connector consumerd all the messages in the topic, still the message are not present in elasticsearch

Comment: You do not see anything in your elasticsearch cluster?

Comment: with trace log level on both elasticseach and the connector, i see nothing that reveals some information on the matter